# Hot to disabled the (not so)intelligent remote load caches in Tom-Select

Tags: javascript, tom-select

I need to show different select lists on a tom-select depending on if the search box is empty or not.
But tom-select is not calling the load function if you remove all characters in the search box.

To make it a little bit clearer:

When you open the tom-select, the proposed select items should be "A" and "B". You type "A" now in the search box, the load function is called and I change the item list and the proposed items are now "AA" "AB".
When you now remove the A with backspace, you should again see the "A" and "B" list, but as tom-select is not calling the load function I cannot replace the list of selects.

Is there any workaround?

Trying to use the answer of XMehdi I tried this code but it does not change a thing

```
        load: (query, callback) =>
        {
            return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) =>
            {
                const productList = await Util.getDataFromBackend("mainpage/productlist", {term: query}, "POST");
                callback(productList);
                reject();
            });
        },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly, you don't have a problem with some caching.
There is simply a setting from TomSelect named `allowEmptyOption` which should be set to `true` to allow loading results even if your search box is empty.
So before your load function, you should define your setting like this:

```js
const select = new TomSelect('your-selector', {
    //[YOUR SETTINGS],
    allowEmptyOption: true,
    load: (query, callback) => {
        const productList = await Util.getDataFromBackend("mainpage/productlist", {term: query}, "POST");
        callback(productList);
        reject();
    },
    //[YOUR OTHER EVENTS/FUNCTIONS]
});
```